# Password not working?!?!

Tags: samsung, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note

Ok this is so frustrating... The Problem im having is i set a new password on my note 5, the password will work to get me into the phone but i want to change it to fingerprint but when i go into setting and Screen Lock Type is asks for current password so i put my password in it says incorrect... I have put in like 15 times making sure i haven't messed it up! Like why would it work to get me into the phone but not to get it to change lock types im so frustrated! I have restarted the phone and nothing! any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it ask for a pin or password? If needed you can also unlock it with your Google account.

Comment: It says enter your current password and then it says incorrect when I use the same one that unlocks the phone? How do I change it with my Google account? I tried android device manager already if that's what you meant, it says they have verified that it has a password already so there is no need to for the new one...

Comment: If you enter a wrong password on your lockscreen for about 5 times, there should appear a "sign in with Google" button. Then the lockscreen will be disabled.